# How do I create Spreadsheet inside a specific folder?

Tags: google-apps-script

Currently, based on certain parameters, I'm creating Spreadsheets using Apps Script via the following code -

```
function newFile() {
  var number = '1';
  var newFile = SpreadsheetApp.create("Roll " + number);
}
```

These new sheets however are being created at the root of Google Drive but instead, I want them to be created under a specific folder.

Unable to find any documentation for it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You want to create a new Spreadsheet to the specific folder.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, your script is modified. After the new Spreadsheet was created to the root folder, the Spreadsheet is moved to the specific folder.

#### Sample script:

```
var folderId = "###"; // Please set the folder ID.
var number = '1';
var fileName = "Roll " + number;

var number = '1';
var newFile = SpreadsheetApp.create("Roll " + number);

var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(newFile.getId());
DriveApp.getFolderById("root").removeFile(file);
folder.addFile(file);
```

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, the new Spreadsheet is directly created to the the specific folder using Drive API. [When you use this script, please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services)

#### Sample script:

```
var folderId = "###"; // Please set the folder ID.
var number = '1';
var fileName = "Roll " + number;

var file = Drive.Files.insert({title: fileName, mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS, parents: [{id: folderId}]});
var newFile = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.id);
```

### References:

- [removeFile() of Class DriveApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#removefilechild)
- [addFile() of Class DriveApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#addfilechild)
- [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)
- [Files: insert of Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/insert)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.